# Correct Way To Move Common Properties

Tags: c#, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I have a set of properties around 20 of them which I need in two different entities (classes) for hierarchical overriding settings system.

So, the simple idea that I can think of is, create an abstract class with those 20 common properties and inherit the abstract class in both the entities.

But that's not going to work, as I also have some more common properties which are common to all the entities. So I'm already inheriting it all the entities. And these 20 properties are not common to all the entities (only two - three of them). Thus I cannot add these 20 properties in existing abstract class.

I tried creating an interface and implementing it, but then I forgot I need to implement the same in concrete classes. So if I have to define them in concrete classes, that's not helping solving my problem.

Any idea? What's the correct way to do that? In near future I may have some more common properties across few entities. So what I should I do, to keep consistency among common properties without re-visiting and re-writing the common properties in each of the entities?

Comment: How about a composite instead of inheritance?

Comment: @CrudaLilium Well composites won't work, as I'm doing it for defining EF Classes.

Answer (score 2):

Have your "common settings" class inherit from your "common entity" class.  Then derive your settings classes from the common settings class.

```
class common_entity {}

class common_settings : common_entity {}

class settings : common_settings {}

class entity : common_entity {}
```

Comment: Well, that way I have to create a lots of classes for every common circle. Is that the right approach?

Comment: I don't understand your sentence, but the answer to your question is Yes, its the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm mistaken, but sometimes we tend to want too much reusability.

See this sample code

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And just because we think that both classes share a `Name` property, we should create a base class:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person : Entity
{
}

public class Company : Entity
{
}
```

I would definitively define a base entity class because any entity should own an unique identifier, but not for a `Name`. And if a subset of entities should own a `Name` I would define an `interface` that would or wouldn't be implemented by concrete entities. Later I'll ask objects if they implement a given interface (i.e. `obj is IWhatever` or `var whatever = obj as IWhatever`).

BTW, as you've already noted in your own solution, while some actions might increase code reusabaility, those may constraint your design negatively.

Just check what you've said:

> I have a set of properties around 20 of them which I need in two
>   different entities

So you've **two** classes which should implement 20 properties and you're scratching your head just because you could define an `interface` and you would need to implement it in those two classes?

Go for the `interface` approach! Doesn't Visual Studio has interface implementation code generation?

Think that a common criticism against OOP is that you end up producing more code, while the key point of OOP is that *more code doesn't mean less maintainability* if you keep your code *simple* and understandable. It's not about coding less but ***coding rightly***.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it makes more sense to me. I'm looking for common coding (single point of coding) approach because, later I may add more properties to these common 20 properties. It's just that I don't want to forget adding them in one class and adding them in another. Thus keeping a common point to define those common properties will save me from that hassle later.